# Searching ClearCase for a checkin with a specific comment

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I've been asked to provide details of a checkin I did about 3 months ago into ClearCase. I know the QC number that was included in the comment but have so far failed utterly to find a way to search ClearCase for a checkin by comment.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a more efficient query for searching a version with a particular comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425) ? Specifically the section below.

> How to find elements and versions with specific comments
>
> I want to find all elements/versions with specific comments like “Jane changed this on 11-26”
>
> M:\my_base_view\my_base_vob>cleartool find -all -exec "cleartool lshistory -minor -fmt \"%n\t%c\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\"" >c:\output.txt
>
> **This will pipe the output to a file and you would have to grep the file for the specific comments you're looking for.
>
> M:\my_base_view\my_base_vob>cleartool find . -version !"lbtype(LABEL_NAME)" -exec "cleartool describe -long %CLEARCASE_PN%" >c:\output2.txt

Looks a bit of a fiddly process, regrettably.

Comment: So *why* was this voted down, when it's relevant and accepted as an answer ?

Comment: Oops sorry: I did the downvote but did not explain why: the answer is a blind copy of the documentation without any additional warning (long, does not detect rmnamed file, ...). "blind" because it includes a second request which has nothing to do with comments... In short: everything I do not like to see in an answer. The principle exposed with the first command is sound though, and can be the *base* of an answer. If Mark managed to solve its issue with it, it is all that matter. Moving on.

Comment: The answer is a reference to the documentation, with relevant bits to work from highlighted. I think that's slightly different. As I noted below, your modifications to the above are correct and worth highlighting.

Comment: I did some testing: lshistory is, for any VOB with medium to large history, a "hurtful" solution (output.txt too large, time of operation too long). I have updated my answer (which is no longer an "addendum" as you put it) for an actual efficient answer.

Comment: -1: "lshistory" after a "find" makes no sense: two queries are made where one is enough.

Answer (score 10):

[Brian Agnew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772035/searching-clearcase-for-a-checkin-with-a-specific-comment/772096#772096) is on the right track, but a word of caution:

- I am sure the second command line is NOT needed (`cleartool find . -version !"lbtype(LABEL_NAME)"...`)
- '`cleartool find -all`' is useful if you think that your file may have been moved, but on a big VOB, that process can be extra long
- without the '`-nvis`' option, it won't find the file if it has been 'rmnamed' (removed)
- using '`lshistory -minor`' is **sheer madness**: on a vob with a few months or years of history, it will simply take too much time. For each element found, it would display the ALL history for *all* versions of that element, without any possibility to refine that set of versions displayed. That solution simply does not scale.
  That, and the `-minor`option of the '`lshistory`' command does not bring any value to the problem at hand: it would only display the *same* version *several* times, just because of internal comments like '`Attached hyperlink "Change@13707xx@\my_pvob`"' or '`Attached hyperlink "Merge@xxxx@\my_vob"`'

You need to refine your query with:

- the type of element wanted (if it is a file: `-type f`)
- the date "`created_since(30-Jan)&&!created_since(28-Feb))`" for instance would limit the date range to consider
- the user

I would use:

```
M:\my_base_view\my_base_vob>
  cleartool find -all -type f -user myLogin -version "{created_since(30-Jan)&&!created_since(28-Feb)}" -exec "cleartool descr -fmt \"%n\t%c\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\"" >c:\output.txt
```

That would only look for files checked-in by me for a certain date period, which is a way to have a smaller set of versions to examine.

Note that I use '`descr`' (the `describe` command) which is only for the *current* version (and not for displaying the all history of an element like '`lshistory`' does).

If your file has been rmnamed, run again the same command with the '-nvis' option (it would only find elements, along with their branches and versions, that are not visible (do not have a standard path name) in the view.

Warning: if you specify a "before" date with a day "in the future" (for instance: '`&&!created_since(28-Apr)}`' whereas we are not the 28th of April yet), it will always select 0 versions (!?).
This is not relevant for your issue, but if you enter a "wrong before date" by mistake, that can lead to the false impression that there is no version to find, where there actually are versions to be found.

Comment: Yes. I think the above is a good addendum. The example in the IBM notes doesn't concern itself with who made the original checkin, and so you can further optimise.