# Clearcase Comment Search GUI based utility

Tags: clearcase

I am working in a project which uses Clearcase for it source code management. Many times we have come across scenarios where we want to find all files having a particular set of keywords in the checkin comments like when tracking files changed for a cahnge request.

As of now, we do it with help of Clean approach suggested in this answer [Searching ClearCase for a checkin with a specific comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772035/searching-clearcase-for-a-checkin-with-a-specific-comment)

But we would really like to get our hands on some utility like fisheye for clearcase so that it becomes easier to do our task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, any utility you would find would be based on the same `cleartool find -exec` command I mention in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/772221/6309) (ie: quite slow)

And FishEye 2.9+ [doesn't support ClearCase anymore](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHEYE/End+of+Support+Announcement+for+IBM+ClearCase).

Only recent version of (commercial) tools like [GoMidjets Visual Annotate](http://www.gomidjets.com/blog/?p=1431) offers some kind of efficient search on those metadata.