# How to find where a string was added at first in code, with ClearCase?

Tags: clearcase

I want to find in which ClearCase label a specific string was added in code?

I am using base ClearCase.

Comment: Are you using base or UCM ClearCase? Which version? Why c++? Are you trying to program that search in c++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [recommended before (8 years ago)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/772221/6309) to limit the scope of your search and use the `exec` clause of a [`cleartool find`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm).

Example:

```
cleartool find -all -type f -user myLogin \
  -version "lbtype(A_LABEL)" \
  -exec ...
```

If you can do so in a dynamic view, you can then directly grep the content of `CLEARCASE_XPN`, the variable set by `cleartool find` for each version found.
It reference an **[extended pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/a/988904/6309)** that (in a dynamic view) you can directly read and grep for your code)

You can do so for each label you can find in your Vob, from the oldest to the newest.

```
Z:myvob>ct lstype -kind lbtype -short
Z:myvob>ct find . -version "lbtype(A_LABEL)" -print
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a specific change in a given source file, the **cleartool annotate** command will give you a good start. If you're familiar with GIT, this is the equivalent of "git blame."

Annotate works only if the element is one of the text file types (text_file, utf?_text_file, etc.) since those store delta information on a per version basis.

One caveat is that this will tell you what version the change came from, but if that version was created by a merge, you may have to backtrack the merge to find the original location of the change. ALMToolbox's "visual annotate" tool does that for you, if I recall correctly.